# Bug in .NET 4.0 DataGridView - flickering, hang

Tags: .net, datagridview, .net-4.0

After changing the target framework of a `.NET` WinForms app from `2.0` to `4.0`, a `DataGridView` on one of the forms flickers and hangs the app.

What is the cause of this?  Is there a work-around?  Has it been resolved in `.NET 4.5`?

Ref: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/657666/datagridview-paint-problem-only-on-net-4-0-works-fine-in-net-3-5

Comment: I've not used these to often, but I'm not aware of such a problem. Can you see what operation is causing it to hang?

Comment: Have you tried looking at what the debugger says?

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? We also have an [issue](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23362351/738851) with DataGridView when upgrading from .Net 3.5 to .Net 4.0.

Comment: @Rob : only the last column can have AutoSize mode 'Fill'.